# Celery Limit the Number of Tasks Running per User

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a task in Celery that looks like this:

```
@app.task(name='task_one')
def task_one(user_id, *args, **kwargs):
    # Long running task
```

This task is created in `views` every time a user submits a form, the task requires a lot of resources and takes around 10 minutes on average to complete.

```
(views.py)
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    task_one.delay(user.id)
...
```

I want to limit the number of `task_one` tasks created per user to one (either active or reserved)

What I'm doing so far, is checking if there is a task active or reserved for that user before creating the task:

```
def user_created_task(active_tasks, reserved_tasks, user_id):
  for task in list(active_tasks.values())[0] + list(reserved_tasks.values())[0]:
    if task['name'] == 'task_one' and task['args'][0] == user_id:
      # Check if there is a `task_one` task created for the user
      return True
  
  return False

def user_tasks_already_running_or_reserved(user_id):
  inspect = app.control.inspect()

  active_tasks = inspect.active()
  reserved_tasks = inspect.reserved()

  if active_tasks is None and reserved_tasks is None:
    # Celery workers are disconnected 
    return False

  return user_created_task(active_tasks, reserved_tasks, user_id)


(views.py)
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    if not user_tasks_already_running_or_reserved(user.id):
        task_one.delay(user.id)
...
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this, instead of inspecting all the workers on every user request, maybe there's a way of adding this condition on Celery before the task runs, so far I haven't found anything in the documentation.

Comment: Any change you can store a flag somewhere that the task has started? Eg. in the database, but also using something like Django's cache etc might be a possible solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation you are describing calls for the use of a distributed lock (because n = 1), but can be more generally described as a distributed semaphore.  Roughly speaking, these locks and mechanisms fall outside of what is built into celery.

As mentioned by the commenters (hat tip: @bernhard vallant), a straightforward implementation of a distributed lock would normally utilize something like a table in a database or a redis [rlock / redlocks](https://redis.io/docs/reference/patterns/distributed-locks/).

In order to utilize [one common implementation](https://github.com/SPSCommerce/redlock-py), you can do the following:

```
from redlock import MultipleRedlockException, Redlock
from django.conf import settings

@app.task(name='task_one', autoretry_for=(MultipleRedlockException, ),  retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 5})
def task_one(user_id, *args, **kwargs):
    # assumes you are using redis for django cache with location
    # set to the redis url
    lock_manager = Redlock([ settings.CACHES['default']['LOCATION'] ])
    lock_name = f'task_one:{user_id}'
    # if the lock fails, we'll get the MultipleRedlockException and trigger
    # celery auto retry
    lock_manager.lock(lock_name, 60 * 60 * 2)  # lock for 2 hours
    try:
        # the main body of what you want to do goes here
        pass
    finally:
        lock_manager.unlock(lock_name)
```

Comment: From the redlock_py documentation there is a couple of wrong instances in here:
The `.lock` directive returns `False` if the lock is already in use, not a MultipleRedlockException.
The locking timeout must also be in miliseconds and not seconds.
See my alternative code in my response.

Answer (score 0):

[2ps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6043170/2ps)'s answer goes in the right direction, but it needs a couple of corrections:

1. If the lock is already in place, the `.lock` directive will return `False`, not cause an exception.
2. Lock timeout is in ms, not seconds
3. The `.unlock` directive needs to receive the lock object, not the lock name or id

Source: https://github.com/SPSCommerce/redlock-py?tab=readme-ov-file

I'm using **Celery** and **django**.
This is what worked for me:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from celery import shared_task
from redlock import Redlock

# Set bind=True to access the task from within
@shared_task(bind=True)
def sample_task(self, user_id):
    # 1. Create the log manager
    lock_manager = Redlock(
        [
            {
                "host": settings.REDIS_HOST,
                "port": settings.REDIS_PORT,
                "db": settings.REDIS_DB,
            },
        ]
    )

    # 2. Set the lock id
    lock_id = f"{user_id}"

    # 3. Try to lock the task with the user_id
    lock = lock_manager.lock(lock_id, 1000 * 60 * 10)  # Lock for 10 minutes

    # 4. Handle lock in use
    if not lock:
        # The lock is in use
        self.retry(countdown=30)  # Retry the task after 30 seconds
    
    try:
        # ... your long task ...
        pass
    finally:
        # Use finally to make sure the unlock happens even if
        # task fails.

        if lock:
            lock_manager.unlock(lock)
```